# EF Core 2.0 update - tracking issue

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am getting changed entity from fronted, mapping it on backend side and simply want to update it in database.
Update is performing like this:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody]Worker worker)
    {
        using (var dbContext= new MyDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

            var entity = dbContext.Workers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == worker.Id);

            if (entity == null) return BadRequest();

            dbContext.Workers.Update(worker);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }}
```

Before this action, i am getting the list of users and sending it to frontend.
Although I set QueryTrackingBehavior to NoTracking, i am getting exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Contract' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'Id:4' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

Where Contract is related entity for Worker which is updated...

Any idea what i am doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

Worker - Contract relation:

```
   public class Worker: IId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contract> Contracts{ get; set; }
}
 public class Contract: IId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public Worker Worker { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the code for Worker and Contract models in the question?

Comment: i've updated the question, thx

Comment: Still you question is incomplete! Where is your IId base class? Why did you omit the other properties of the Worker and Contract classes?

Comment: It's  just an interface with Id property, and another properties are just simple strings

Comment: Okay..See my answer below..I have already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay! got the problem in your code. You didn't map the updated entity to the existing entity that you pulled from the database. You have to map the updated entity to the existing entity. To do so you can use `AutoMapper` or explicit mapping as follows:

You can solve the problem as follows:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody]Worker worker)
{
        using (var dbContext= new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entityToBeUpdated = dbContext.Workers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == worker.Id);

            if (entity == null) return BadRequest();

            entityToBeUpdated.Property1 = worker.Property1;
            entityToBeUpdated.Property2 = worker.Property2;
            // Do the same for the other changed properties as well

            dbContext.Workers.Update(entityToBeUpdated);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
 }
```

Alternatively you can try as follows:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody]Worker worker)
{
      using (var dbContext= new MyDbContext())
      {
           var entityToBeUpdated = dbContext.Workers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == worker.Id);

           if (entity == null) return BadRequest();

           entityToBeUpdated.Property1 = worker.Property1;
           entityToBeUpdated.Property2 = worker.Property2;
           // Do the same for the other changed properties as well.

           dbContext.SaveChanges();
           return Ok();
      }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if i have for example 10 more properies, i will have to remap them manually? Or to use automapper...?

Comment: Is there any other way or i have to check every single property if it's changed?

Comment: You can use both. But I personally prefer AutoMaper to minimize the lines of code.

Comment: I tried with automapper, with entity = _mapper.Map<Worker>(workerDto), but ef core can not see changes in entity...

Comment: ok, seems that _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(worker);
   _context.Radnici.Update(entity); solved my problem... thanks anyway

Comment: @zlaayaa Configuring AutoMapper in EF Core quite different from EF6. Here is link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXvPmxrrnQY

Comment: SOLVED Might be helpful to someone who encounter the same problem. I tried to update everything from parent entity, making queriable if it exist first. In that part, EF Core start with tracking, and when i try to update related data, it is already tracked. No need for that, you can find it by context.Entity.Find(id). Also, when you want to update parent entity in a way that you want to delete one of it's related collection items, do that in that specific child entity, and database will just set null for that deleted child(with assumption you declared that relation in OnModelCreating() method.